# Create vector from distance?

Tags: math, vector, geometry

For example, I have a drone, I do not know the speed and position of this drone. However, I know its distance to an object thanks to the sensor inside. As (x,y,z). Is it possible for me to create a vector between this object and my drone?

If I can draw vectors, I want to create an inverse vector from object to drone.

Comment: If you use spherical polar coordinates (r, theta, phi), you have r as distance, but without more information, you can't turn it into a 3d vector.

Comment: The distance to an object lets you place the drone on a circle with that object at the centre and of radius equal to the distance.  Distance to another object will, if the two circles intersect, place the drone at one of two points.  Distances to three objects and you've got a fix.  From a sequence of fixes you can calculate speed and direction.

Comment: But I don't know the position of the object, how do I place it in the center

Comment: The trivial answer is "yes: the displacement vector is (x, y, z)" if you choose your frame of reference correctly. If you don't like this, you need to provide more information.

Comment: To compute this, you need to know the relative orientation of the drone.

Comment: Thanks .I did it while taking the reference to drone